# How to improve long text readability in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, readability

I need to start reading [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_toc.htm).

I have to admit that compared to other informative guides/tutorials/articles out there, this guide isn't so cluttered. However, I still find it a [little bit hard to read](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPOverviewandHistory.htm), especially when reading for several hours.

I don't know if it's the font, the contrast or the spacing, but this is why I've always preferred learning from books rather than from the internet.

What can I do to make this guide more readable? I am reading it on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you feel that the website content doesn't fit for you then you can copy&paste the page content to notepad for offline reading.

But if you want to change the font color or background color of web page then you can use [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) extension for Chrome which has an ability to edit the css.

[image]

Also if you want to increase the font size then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to increase it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to decrease it.

**When you increase the font size**.

[image]

**when you edit the page using stylebot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **I've always preferred learning from books**

According to [the site you linked to](http://www.tcpipguide.com/index.htm):
*"it is also available [as a print book!](http://www.tcpipguide.com/buybook.htm)"*

> **What can I do to make this guide more readable? I am reading it on Google Chrome.**

- Change the font size
- Change the font
- Resize the window to flow the text into narrower columns (a technique used
  in newspapers for readability reasons)

[image: before]
[image: settings]
[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little bit of a pain as there are so many pages, but have you considered using a webapp like [Pocket](http://getpocket.com)? You can use their Chrome extension to add pages to your queue, then read them in the app instead of on the page. I like the way Pocket formats pages for reading. Plus, you can then read them on a phone or tablet, as well.